# Make scrollable a JPanel child with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

I've some problem to make a JPanel component to be scrollable... I've spent more than 3 hours to make this works, but without success and that is why I ask your help!

The Window class:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
    public Window(String title) {
        super();

        Dimension dimension = IHM.getDimension();

        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setSize(dimension.width, dimension.height);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMaximumSize(dimension);
        this.setMinimumSize(dimension);
        this.setContentPane(new Container());
        this.setBackground(IHM.getBlue());
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The Container class:

```
public class Container extends JPanel {
    public static Boolean debug = true;
    private Dimension lastDimension = new Dimension(0, 0);

    public Container() {
        // Layout
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Panel configurations
        this.setLayout(layout);

        /**
         * HEADER
         */
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;

        this.add(new HeaderPanel(), gbc);

        /**
         * LEFT
         */
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        JPanel leftPanel = new LeftPanel();

        JScrollPane leftPanelScrollable = new JScrollPane(leftPanel);

        leftPanelScrollable.setViewportView(leftPanel);
        leftPanelScrollable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        leftPanelScrollable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        leftPanelScrollable.setBounds(10, 10, leftPanel.getWidth() - 50, leftPanel.getHeight() - 50);

        this.add(leftPanelScrollable, gbc);

        // ...
    }
}
```

And the leftPanel class:

```
public class LeftPanel extends JPanel {
    private static Dimension dimension = new Dimension(IHM.getWidth() / 2, IHM.getHeight() - 220);

    public LeftPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(dimension);

        // Add the labels
        this.addLabel();

        // Add the radios
        this.addRadios();

        this.setAutoscrolls(true);
    }
}
```

Please see the screenshots, I don't have any scrollbar :(

The result in picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q40Ct.png]

Do you have any idea about the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider telling us more about what problems you may be having.

Comment: Note that we'd much rather see details about the code and the problem then see how many hours you've spent working on it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I've added a screenshot. About the details, all important codes are presents, about the addLabels and addRadios method, I do not think this is important... rectify me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After removing the defined size and preferredSize for each JPanel, after set the GridBagConstraints `weighty`, `weightx` and `fill` to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` and finally use the `setBoxLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))` for my leftPanel, everything works well! Thanks anyway everybody.

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 2):

```
leftPanelScrollable.setBounds(10, 10, leftPanel.getWidth(), leftPanel.getHeight());
```

This should do the damage. The above method forces the `JScrollPane` be the same size of the underlying panel. Let the layout manager do the work.

<sub>P.S. I haven't tested it.</sub>

---

You should also try making your `JPanel` implement [`Scrollable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) and set

```
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
```

And

```
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
```

Return false.

Comment: I tried with more height and width and without the setBounds call, but that's make no difference and that is why i let the original size. Sorry for the confusion, i'll update my post immediately about the size with more width and height to not make more confusion. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try with LESS width and height... This will activate the scrolling.

Comment: I tried setBounds with more or less height and width, but the result is the same. Thanks anyway

Comment: Added another solution, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I've also added getScrollableUnitIncrement, getScrollableBlockIncrement and getPreferredScrollableViewportSize methods (that is required by the implementation).

[When i return null for the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize method i get that](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/620881Capturede769cran20160615a768013038.png)
[When i return the current dimension for the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize method i get that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q40Ct.png). The problem maybe come from the preferedSize defined for each panel, but i'm not sure and I do not know why...

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
```

Don't manually set the preferred size. The layout manager of the panel will determine the preferred size. The default layout manager for a JPanel is the `FlowLayout` which will give a preferred size as if all components are on the same line this is obviously not what you want, so use a different layout manager.

```
this.setAutoscrolls(true);
```

This is not required for scrolling.

```
    JScrollPane leftPanelScrollable = new JScrollPane(leftPanel);
    leftPanelScrollable.setViewportView(leftPanel);
```

There is no need to set the viewport view. When you create the scroll pane the component you specify will be added to the viewport.

```
   leftPanelScrollable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    leftPanelScrollable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

There is no need to set the scrollbar policy. The scrollbars will appear automatically when required (once you get your code working) and let the layout managers do their job.

```
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.setLayout(layout);
```

I suggest you can use a `BorderLayout` which is easier to use. Just add the "headerPanel" to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`. Then add your "leftPane" to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Then as the frame is resized all the extra space will go to the `CENTER` and scrollbars will appear as required.

> all important codes are presents

Until the problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't imports. If the above suggestions done help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I removed the setSize and setMaximumSize call from the Window class and I removed all setPreferedSize calls on JPanel childs.

I forgot to add weightx and weighty property and that is why I had to set the size manually.

Now, my problem and I can only scroll horizontaly. I will update my first post tomorrow.

About the layout, this is a requirement, but I thanks you for your suggestion. 

And about the important codes... I know what is important or not. I prefer to receive questions to show some more code instead of a lot of boring code. This is my opinion.

Comment: `Now, my problem and I can only scroll horizontaly` - I could give you the answer, but you haven't posted your SSCCE so apparently you no longer need any help.